# Excel Userform TextBox.Value Populate MS Word Bookmarks

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, userform

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

 Dim wApp As Object
 Dim wDoc As Object

 Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 wApp.Visible = True

 Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="C:\template1.dotm ", ReadOnly:=False)
    With wDoc.Selection
    .Bookmarks("bookmark1") = UserForm5.TextBox1.Value
    .Bookmarks("bookmark2") = UserForm5.TextBox2.Value
    End With

 WordDoc.Close
 WordApp.Quit
 Set WordDoc = Nothing
 Set WordApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Hello All,

I was hoping that someone could help me on this one. As shown on the code above, I am trying to get the userform textbox value and populate it to MS Word using bookmarks.

The issue is that when I click command button 3 on the userform, the MS word opens but the bookmarks is still empty i.e. no value

I would appreciate the help as I have been trying to resolve this for hours. Many thanks.

Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bookmark commands need a Range and Text properties. Example

```
.Bookmarks("bookmark1").Range.Text = UserForm5.TextBox1.Value
```

Comment: Hi Rich, Thank you so much. My other problem is how do i save the open word document with a new name in a different location?

Comment: Also change `WordDoc.Close`  to   `WordDoc.Close True` or if is wDoc?

Comment: Seems to me as a case of non consistant use of the same variables (WDoc : WordDoc; cf. wApp : WordApp) - `Option Explicit` needed!. BTW within the userform's `CommandButton3_Click` event one should use the prefix `Me.` instead of `UserForm5.` :-)

Comment: Thank you all for the advice and help. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Kev, to save the document you would use WordDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:=xxxxx